# Running .BAT file from Access

Tags: vba, batch-file

I am having trouble running a .bat file from access. The .bat file is created, the log is created (with nothing in it), the .bat file will run when I click on it in Windows explorer, I just cannot get it to run using the .RUN command.

```
sFTP = "ftp -s:FTPCMD.TXT > Z:\Recon\FTPUtilSrc\ftprslt.txt"
Open sFileName For Output As #2
Print #2, sFTP
'Print #2, "EXIT"
Close #2
oShell.Run sFileName, 0, True
```

Edit:

```
sFileName = "Z:\Recon\FTPUtilSrc\MYFTP.BAT"
sFTP = "ftp -s:FTPCMD.TXT > Z:\Recon\FTPUtilSrc\ftprslt.txt"
Open sFileName For Output As #2
Print #2, sFTP
Print #2, "EXIT"
Close #2
oShell.run sFileName, 0, True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing a couple things to see what is happening:

```
sFileName = "Z:\Recon\FTPUtilSrc\MYFTP.BAT"
sFTP = "ftp -s:FTPCMD.TXT > Z:\Recon\FTPUtilSrc\ftprslt.txt"
Open sFileName For Output As #2
Print #2, sFTP
Print #2, "PAUSE" 'PAUSE forces the command prompt window to stay open.  This temporarily allows you to see if there are any issues with the ftp statment.
Close #2
oShell.run sFileName, 0, True '3 is "Activates the window and displays it as a maximized window." according to msdn.  This will allow you to see the execution of the ftp statment
```

See if those changes help you identify the issue so you can change it back.  Incidentally, I tested the code by running the following, and it worked as expected which leads me to believe it's an issue with the ftp command.

```
Public Sub TestBat()
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    sFileName = "C:\Temp\MYECHO.bat" '"Z:\Recon\FTPUtilSrc\MYFTP.BAT"
    sFTP = "echo ""hi"" > C:\Temp\test.txt" '"ftp -s:FTPCMD.TXT > Z:\Recon\FTPUtilSrc\ftprslt.txt"
    Open sFileName For Output As #2
    Print #2, sFTP
    Print #2, "PAUSE"
    Close #2
    oShell.Run sFileName, 3, True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks the Pause command helped alot. Its looking for my batch file on the drive when its located on the Z drive. That fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Dim cmd_str As String
cmd_str = "cmd.exe /C ftp -s:FTPCMD.TXT > Z:\Recon\FTPUtilSrc\ftprslt.txt"
Call Shell(cmd_str, vbNormalFocus)
```

Comment: I think its close but its still doing the same thing. Do I need to add the path to the .bat file? It's creating the ftprslt.txt file, but not running the .bat

Comment: @user2183985 Sorry, I think I had misunderstood part of this. Where are you defining a path to the batch file in your script. It would also be worth adding a print statement for the path just to double check how this is coming out.

Comment: Chris' code runs the ftp dump directly without using a batch file... why do you need it to run from a batch file?

Comment: @Blackhawk Chris' code didn't work. It still did the same thing my code did before. I added and update with and extra line of code that displays my batch file.